Explicit Construction of a 2 sheeted covering of the torus.
I'm studying algebraic topology from Hatcher for a course. The course instructor asked us to classify all of the possible 2 sheeted coverings of a torus $S^1 \times S^1$(not necessarily connected) using the action of the fundamental group on the fibre $p^{-1}(x_0)$ and relating it to a conjugacy class of a homomorphism from $\pi_1(X,x_0)$ to $S_2$.
The way we obtain the various possibilities from the action is clear to me, but I was stuck trying to actually construct an explicit covering for the torus corresponding to the conjugacy class of the homomorphism determined by $(0,1) \mapsto (1\ 2), (1,0) \mapsto (1\ 2)$. The other three cases were straightforward. It is just constructing the space that would do the job in this case that puzzles me. I don't need to prove it exists, but to construct such a cover explicitly.
Again, apologies if this has already been answered. I haven't been able to find an answer as yet. Any hints on how to construct the 2 sheeted covering are welcome.

What are the other coverings you've found? $(x,y)\mapsto(\pm x,\pm y)$ is a good place to start.

The three covers were: 1: If $(0,1)\mapsto \operatorname{id} \in S_2$ and $(1,0) \mapsto \operatorname{id}$, then the 2 sheeted covering is just two disjoint tori. If $(0,1)\mapsto \operatorname{id}$ and $(1,0) \mapsto (1\ 2)$, we get the two sheeted covering $S^1\times d(S^1)$ where $d: z\mapsto z^2$. The third covering space is likewise $d(S^1)\times S^1$ for $(0,1)\mapsto (1\ 2), (1,0)\mapsto \operatorname{id}$.

And what about $d\times d$?

I tried that at first, but wouldn't that give us a four sheeted covering of the torus instead of a two sheeted one?

The analogy I was given by another student was that the first nontrivial one would be like dipping a tube in batter and observing the two "tubes" obtained. The other one would be a torus twisted and folded onto itself. Doing them simultaneously would give me a four sheeted covering. Please correct me if I'm wrong in using this analogy.

Yes. And all 3 connected 2-sheeted coverings exist "between" this and the identity map. Again, see my first comment. Note that $(x,y)\mapsto(-x,y)$ is an action preserving the map $d\times id$.

I see! So the map $p_1\times p_2$ would need to be preserved under the action $(x,y)\mapsto (-x, -y) $ but isn't $d\times d$. Am I right in saying that?

Yes that's right. Can you see what the map is?

Yes thank you! I did eventually get it but I forgot to reply here. Thanks for your help! I upvoted your answer as well. Apologies for the late reply.

Just recording an answer for posterity.
Connected $2$-sheeted coverings are classified by index $2$ subgroups inside $\pi_1(\mathbb{T}^2)\cong\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$, and these are classified by surjective homomorphisms $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, of which there are $3$: there are $2$ choices for where each generator goes, so $2\cdot2=4$ maps, but one of those is the trivial map and not surjective.
There is a $4$-sheeted covering map $D:\mathbb{T}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{T}^2$ given by $D(x,y)=(x^2,y^2)$, and all $2$-sheeted coverings "factor" through this one. The key idea is that $n$-sheeted coverings of $\mathbb{T}^2$ correspond to index $n$ subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$. The special thing about the torus, is that once we know the index $n$ subgroup, we can build the covering map via a $2\times2$ integer matrix that maps the generators of $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ into this subgroup; this matrix will necessarily have determinant $\pm n$. So for example, the map $D$ can be represented by the matrix
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
2&0\\0&2
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
Here the columns are the generators of the index $4$ subgroup, and the rows read off the exponents in the map $D$. We can look at a factorization of this matrix such as
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
2&0\\0&2
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}2&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&2\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
The two matrices on the right correspond to two (different) index $2$ subgroups, so give rise to two (different) $2$-sheeted covering maps. Reading off the exponents, we can take $\rho_1(x,y)=(x^2,y)$ and $\rho_2(x,y)=(x,y^2)$. A more interesting factorization is
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
2&0\\0&2
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&-1\end{pmatrix}^2
\end{equation}
The columns of the matrix on the right generate the third (and final) index $2$ subgroup, and the associated covering map is $\rho_3(x,y)=(xy,xy^{-1})$. Note that this factorization shows $D\equiv\rho_3^2$, as can be checked directly.
Because we care about the subgroups, changing the basis of a subgroup -- which corresponds to doing some elementary operations on the matrix -- will give the same subgroup, and hence the same covering map (up to isomorphism).  The matrix above, with the $-1$ entry, can be changed by adding the two columns together, to get
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
1&2\\1&0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
This corresponds to the $2$-sheeted covering map $\rho_4(x,y)=(xy^2,x)$. We can see that $\rho_3$ and $\rho_4$ are isomorphic covering maps via the homeomorphism $h(a,b)=(ab,b)$, so that $\rho_4\equiv\rho_3\circ h$.

Let me point out that this can also be interpreted geometrically as follows: If you identify $T^2$ with the quotient $\mathbb{R}^2 / \Lambda$, where $\Lambda \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is the unit lattice, then the quotient map $\mathbb{R}^2 \to T^2$ is the universal cover, and the coverings in your answer can be obtained as the quotient of $\mathbb{R}^2$ by the lattices generated by the columns of the respective matrices (since they are subgroups of $\Lambda$).
